# Cannot install with pipx

Tags: python, installation, pip, package, pipx

I cannot install packages using pipx.

`python3 -m pipx ensurepath` worked perfectly.

The command `pipx install eth-brownie` outputs the error:
"Error installing eth-brownie"

It seems to be a pipx issue because I also tried to install other packages using pipx and the error message was the same.

Python version: 3.9.7

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Which command did you run? Which is your Python version? Please provide more details.

Comment: @DiegoRamirez I edited my question and provided the details you asked for.

Comment: With the description provided, I reproduced by running `python -m pipx ensurepath` and then `pipx install eth-brownie`, but everything worked fine. Maybe you have a certain configuration that I don't have. Did `pipx` give some details?